# How to specify an initial state on page load using js?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, hide

I have a brand within a navbar and I want it hidden before the first 100px. But when loading the page, the brand is visible. Only after scrolldown the page the code works.

Consider this example.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(window).scrollTop()>100){
     $("#theDiv").fadeIn();
  }else{
     $("#theDiv").fadeOut();
  }
});
```

[VIEW DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtGK6/)

When you open the link, the yellow square will be visible (as unwanted). When you scrolldown, the square is still visible (as desired). But when you return to the first 100px, the square disappears (as desired) .

How to make the square invisible on page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple way without making too many changes.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    fader();
});

function fader(t){
       if($(window).scrollTop()>100){
         $("#theDiv").fadeIn(t);
      }else{
         $("#theDiv").fadeOut(t);
      }   
}

$(document).ready(function() { fader(0); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/ZtGK6/596/

If you don't want that fade at the start let me know.

Comment: Almost! I just don't want the fade at the start. There's a way to use "hiding" on page load?

Comment: Great! It worked perfectly in my navbar. Thank you so much , garryp. ^o^